# Code signing applications within Windows for Application Whitelisting

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, certificate, code-signing

Here is my dilemma, I am trying to perform Application Whitelisting based off of publisher which in turn is based on whether or not the application has been signed. The issue is, unsigned software does not have a publisher listed. My idea was to then vet unsigned software and if approved for use we could sign it with our internal code signing certificate. I tested this process out using Microsoft`s signtool and it seemed to work but here is the issue. When I tested it out I did it on an installer.exe, after that I installed the application in which it then created a file in Program files with the other installed .exes that came with it. When I check on the signature of the .exes that were installed in the Program Files it says that they are unsigned! I know i could go and run the same command on those to sign them but that is not feasible if we were to deploy this to numerous end systems. My question is: Is there a way to sign the installer to which when installing it, the .exes that are installed will also be signed by our internal certificate? Or is there a way to install the application and sign the necessary files and then repackage it for deployment? Sorry for the long question but I cant think of a way to get this done and I figure since Application Whitelisting is hot right now someone must have had a similar issue. Also, I know that we can use Path or Hash but that is not what I am trying to do here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend signing vendor code with your corporate signature.  I'm not sure if you are doing that or not but if you are, I'd suggest being careful.   Unless you know exactly what's in the code, signing someone else's code is just not a good idea.

You are correct that the exes from the installer are unsigned; that's how the process works.  When you sign an executable, you are only signing that exe and not the content of the cab file it extracts and lays down.

I use McAfee Application Control with signed installers, and that works out well.  I trust my company's signature as an updater (allows it to change files), and it installs the software as desired without signing each executable.

So, let's go through the questions (sorry if this is long).

Is there a way to sign the installer and sign its subordinate exes?  Not that I know of.  Files are signed individually.  You could probably automate that somehow; that's for a different thread.  I'm no expert on signatures but in my experience when I've signed an installer that hasn't recursed into the installed content.

is there a way to install the application and sign the necessary files and then repackage it for deployment?  Technically possible.  Keep in mind that if you repackage a vendor install, you lose support on the install.  There are several snapshotting tools out there that would do a delta on what was installed and would let you gather that info and then sign the files.  That's an application packaging question on how to create the install from a snapshot.